# VS2010 indirect reference issue

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I have these VS2010 .net projects/assemblies AssemblyA, AssemblyB, AssemblyC.

AssemblyC  references both AssemblyA and AssemblyB 
AssemblyB references only AssemblyA

Every project in its own solution.
All references are set Specific Version = False

Everytime I build AssemblyA I get the following errors in AssemblyC

"The project currently contains references to more than one version of AssemblyA, a direct reference to version 4.0.1.27700 and an indirect reference (through 'AssemblyB.SomeClass') to version 4.0.1.33206. Change the direct reference to use version 4.0.1.33206 (or higher) of AssemblyA."

The only workaround I have found is to 1) build AssemblyB every time I build AssemblyA 2) remove both references in AssemblyC and add them back again.

Is this normal? Any other solution?

Comment: Are all the projects in the same solution? If so, did you add references to the .dll files in the bin directories, or did you add references to the projects themselves?

Answer (score 0):

"Specific Version = False" only tells the compiler to link to whatever version you happen to have locally.  Once compiled, it still needs the exact version you had when you compiled.  So when you build a new version of AssemblyA, AssemblyB doesn't know about it and you end up with the error.

Is there any reason why these are not part of the same solution?  If you are making changes to AssemblyA, and AssemblyB uses it, it seems reasonable to rebuild AssemblyB as well.

Comment: The main reason for not being in the same solution is that they are quite big projects. Loading them all together takes too long. Anyway, this was not the case with VS2003 (I think so). I was able to open the forms designer even if AssemblyA version had changed.